# Python dictionary breaking the laws of python

Tags: python, dictionary

When I do:

```
>>> d={True:'yes',1:'no',1.0:'maybe'}
>>> d
```

I receive an output of:

```
>>> {True:'maybe'}
```

It's not only that some of my keys are deleted but also the value it was holding changed.

Why is True given priority over another bool keys?

Comment: Interesting or not, it's a duplicate

Comment: Why was my comment deleted?

Comment: It is explained in detail here - https://dbader.org/blog/python-mystery-dict-expression

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The three keys True, 1 and 1.0 compare equal to each other and all have the same [hash](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=hash#hash) (try `hash(True)`, `hash(1)` and `hash(1.0)` in the Python REPL), so they all correspond to the same slot in the dictionary. The last value to be set wins - 'maybe' in this case.

Note that if the keys weren't equal, they would be stored separately even if they hashed to the same slot in the dictionary.

Comment: May be they should be hashing the type too

Comment: @sureshvv: That would add overhead, and break the equality relationship seen outside of `dict`. Making a special case for `dict` would be confusing. The OP could always make the `dict` with a `tuple` key, where the first element is the value and the second the type if they really need that.

Comment: I don't think that would be desirable in general.

Comment: is it not like that only immutable data types like tuple uses hash functions whereas dictionary is mutable so it is not based on hashing?

Comment: @RICKY: The `dict` itself is mutable, but its *keys* must be hashable (and logically immutable). Hashing is how it looks up keys efficiently.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Tuples are immutable; dicts are mutable and are based on hashing. In general dict keys are immutable because allowing a key to be mutated would probably change it's hash, so you wouldn't be able to find it in the dict again.

Comment: I mean, what @ShadowRanger said.

Comment: Thats very interesting. Similarly, `set([1,1.0,True])` is `set([1])`. Funny :)

Comment: Yeah i got that. I was just thinking of dictionary as a whole although keys are immutable and must be unique at the  hash level . Thanks @babbageclunk . My doubt got clear so quickly i could not imagine this :D

Comment: Equal values will always have the same hash. It's more important that these values are equal than that their hashes are equal. The root of the surprising behavior here is that `True == 1`

Comment: One more thing is troubling me , I agree that the last value is taken the final value but why is True the key and not 1 or 1.0?

Comment: It's essentially doing `d = {}; d[True] = 'yes'; d[1] = 'no'; d[1.0] = 'maybe'`. So it's keeping the first key (because they're all equal), but always doing the assignment, so you get the last value.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I understand why it works the way it does. It is less than ideal. Without explicit type coercion, these values should not be equal. And their hashes should be distinct. Being correct is more important rather than explain these hideous gotchas.

Comment: @sureshvv I think the problem is that making 1 != 1.0 would also be pretty weird and surprising in other ways. The fact that True == 1 is unfortunate but would be really hard to fix without a major breaking change (probably way worse than str/bytes in 2 -> 3).

Comment: @babbageclunk why not have 1 != 1.0 but 1 == int(1.0) and float(1) == 1.0?

Comment: There's no technical reason Python couldn't do that, but it's made the decision to allow comparison between floats for usability.